# Zabbix active agent can't connect to Zabbix server - connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, zabbix

I am already using active agents on other servers and everything works really nice. I've performed installation of Zabbix agent on new server and I've set the same config as in other active agents. The problem is my agent can't connect to the server.

Logs:

```
End of zbx_tls_connect():FAIL error:'SSL_connect() I/O error: [0x00002746] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.'

active check configuration update from [hidden_address:10051] started to fail (TCP successful, cannot establish TLS to [[hidden_address]:10051]: SSL_connect() I/O error: [0x00002746] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)

End of refresh_active_checks():FAIL
```

I am sure that PSK key and ID is set correctly in both agent and server. My config (works on other agents):

```
LogFile=C:\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.log
DebugLevel=5
Server=hidden_address
ListenPort=10051
Hostname=hidden_name
ServerActive=hidden_address
EnableRemoteCommands=1

TLSConnect=psk
TLSAccept=psk
TLSPSKFile=C:\Zabbix\conf\client.txt
TLSPSKIdentity=hidden_id
```

Port is opened on both sides and I have checked with Test-NetConnection in Powershell that I can connect from agent to server on specifed port (10051).

Any idea what else I can check or try to do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings on encryption option for the host on web interface.

The content on `C:\Zabbix\conf\client.txt` must be the same value on web and file

Comment: Value is exactly the same